# How to make an R file available online?

Tags: r, url

I am trying to publish a data set online to use in a blog. I tried to use Dropbox and GoogleDrive, but the link created by these apps is not loaded in R.

The idea is having the data online, so someone can access it:

```
 load(url("http://www.url.com/student/data.Rdata"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're posting in on a blog, can't you host it there too?

Comment: Post it on github.  You could use a gist and then people can get the data with `devtools::source_gist()`

Comment: I think Dropbox works fine. You can put the file in Dropbox' "Public" folder, select the file (usually with a right click, depends on OS), and choose "Dropbox -> Copy Publik Link". You can then download the file in an `R` session and save it to "myscript.r" with `download.file("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/..../the_script.r", "myscript.r")`, where the URL is the pasted "Public Link" mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know of any ways to publish an R data file to the web, but is there any reason that you wouldn't go the standard CSV route?

To publish a CSV from Google Drive:

1. Open a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing.
2. Click the File menu.
3. Select Publish to the Web.
4. While the entire file will be published, some file types have more publishing options:

   1. Spreadsheet: Choose to publish the entire spreadsheet or individual sheets. You can also choose a publishing format (web page, .csv, .tsv, .pdf, .xlsx, .ods).
   2. Presentation: Choose how quickly to advance the slides.
   3. Drawing: Choose the image size for your drawing.
5. Click Publish.
6. Copy the URL.

From there you can easily read that file back into R using the following:

```
require(RCurl)
data <- getURL("add your URL here")
wine <- read.csv(textConnection(data))
summary(data)
```

Here is a working example for you to test:

```
require(RCurl)
wine <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xIq-hyZM3P6__0cdqpXqDWpqQebXBnOdy1nS159wQ-A/pub?gid=616153433&single=true&output=csv")
wine <- read.csv(textConnection(wine))
summary(wine)
```

Similar solutions are available for Dropbox as well.

Comment: When I try to load from GoogleDrive: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate